# Filter through Python list to find common elements

Tags: python, list, tuples, grouping

I'm trying to find an efficient way to loop through elements in a list, and to group common elements together into another list, grouplist.

**Exmaple**

```
In[]: grouplist = []

In[]: filelist
Out[]:['C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx',
        'C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx',
        'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx']
```

I want to find a group of common patterns, with different integers. So in this case,

First iteration grouplist =

```
 C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx
 C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx
```

Second Iteration =

```
 C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx
```

Third Iteration =

```
 C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx
 C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx
```

Comment: Your description seems to say that you want to group the files by the number at the end of the name, but your examples seem to be grouping by the name.  Which is it?

Comment: What about `C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx,`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, group by name only. I'll try to make it more clear

Comment: @SIslam Yes iterate until all the files are done

Comment: @user2877133, what is the story with  `C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` is your friend:

```
from itertools import groupby


filelist = [
    'C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx', 
    'C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx', 
    'C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx', 
    'C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx',
    'C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx',
    'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx']

key_fn = lambda s: s.rsplit('-',1)[0]

# before grouping, list has to be sorted
filelist = sorted(filelist, key=key_fn)

# usually use the same key_fn for grouping as was used for sorting
for key, grouped_file_names in groupby(filelist, key=key_fn):
    # groupby returns an iterator of tuples
    # the first element of the tuple is the grouped key value
    # the second element is a generator of the items that matched that key
    # (YOU MUST CONSUME THIS GENERATOR BEFORE MOVING ON TO THE NEXT KEY)
    print '\n'.join(list(grouped_file_names))
    print
```

prints

```
C:\South-California-North-5.xlsx

C:\West-California-East-1.xlsx

C:\West-California-North-10.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-5.xlsx

C:\West-California-South-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying this out, I think I'm almost there. How do I change the parameters of the key if I'm trying to group by a string instead?  Example, group by amount of people                                                                                C:\West-California-South-1people-Poverty.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3people-Poverty.xlsx

Comment: 'key_fn = lambda s: s.rsplit('-',2)[0]' In this case?

Comment: Run the `key_fn` yourself against several test strings, and tweak it until it gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary in order to categorize your paths based on the location name.

For separating the location name from the trailing id you can use `str.rsplit()` then use `dict.setdefault()` method by passing a `set()` object in it in order to preserve the unique names:

```
>>> lst=['C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx', 'C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx','C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx','C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx','C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx','C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx']

>>> d = {}
>>> new = [path.rsplit('-',1) for path in lst]

>>> for i,j in new:
...     d.setdefault(i,set()).add(i+'-'+j)
... 

>>> d.values()
[set(['C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx']),
 set(['C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx','C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx']), 
 set(['C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx']),
 set(['C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx', 'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx'])]
>>>
```

Comment: @haifzhan Sorry I missed that, fixed.

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` is the new way of building dicts like this, much cleaner looking, and no need to build a throwaway set every time you call `setdefault` when the key already exists.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire It doesn't create throwaway set when the key already exists. The essence of this argument is to preserve the values when the keys is already exist.

Comment: Look again. That second argument to `setdefault` *always* creates an empty set on every call, whether the key exists or not. This is why the constructor to a `defaultdict` of sets (for example) is not `defaultdict(set())` but `defaultdict(set)`. The argument is a factory method to be used when a never-before-seen key is used.

Comment: @Kasramvd thanks for this. Would it be possible to split for something in between? Example  C:\\West-California-South-**1people**-Males.xlsx

Comment: Yes in this case you just split with `-`. then choose the 4th (index 3) as the key. `new = [path.rsplit('-') for path in lst]` then in your loop `for i,j,k,z,t in new:d.setdefault(z,set()).add('-'.join(i,j,k,z,t)) `

Comment: @Kasramvd Hm, been trying that. Looks like it splits everything beyond the specified index?

Comment: @Kasramvd - last try. When you call `xyz(100, set())`, the second argument is a constructed set object that is passed to `xyz`. Likewise, `dict.setdefault(key, set())` will *always* construct a set object to be passed to setdefault, even if setdefault determines that the key exists already and so the provided set is not required - but it still had to be built.  Conversely `defaultdict(set)` *doesn't* build a set until the `defaultdict.__missing__` is called with a new key - it is only at that time that the given factory method is used to construct the initial value for the new key.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I know what you say, and how the `defaultdict` has been implemented. But I think first time that we call the function python will create a global object from empty `set` and by the time it doesn't get change python wont create another one. You can see this from python byte-code using `dis` module. I think it's how the garbage collector works in python. But I think this is not True for immutable objects, There is a good benchmark in this like http://tomron.net/2014/08/25/setdefault-vs-get-vs-defaultdict/ But I'm not very sure about the reason of this difference!!

Answer (score 1):

use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)

for fle in l:
    k, rest = fle.rsplit("-", 1)
    d[k].add("{}-{}".format(k, rest))

for k,v in d.items():
    print "\n".join(v)
    print
```

Output:

```
C:\West-California-East-1.xlsx

C:\West-California-North-10.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-5.xlsx

C:\South-California-North-5.xlsx

C:\West-California-South-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
```

If you want to preserve the order the elements are first seen use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()

for fle in l:
    k, rest = fle.rsplit("-", 1)
    d.setdefault(k,set()).add("{}-{}".format(k, rest))

for k,v in d.items():
    print "\n".join(v)
    print
```

Output:

```
C:\West-California-North-10.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-5.xlsx

C:\West-California-East-1.xlsx

C:\West-California-South-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx

C:\South-California-North-5.xlsx
```

If you don't have digits in the name you can also `str.translate` instead of splitting:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)

for fle in l:
    d[fle.translate(None,"0123456789")].add(fle)

for k,v in d.items():
    print "\n".join(v)
    print
```

Output:

```
C:\West-California-East-1.xlsx

C:\West-California-South-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx

C:\South-California-North-5.xlsx

C:\West-California-North-10.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-5.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `sorted` and `regex`- You can modify and will have more control over this sorting- just change the `sorter` function.

```
import re

d = ['C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx',
        'C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx',
        'C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx',
        'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx']

def sorter(s):
    direction1 = re.findall(r'(\w+)-California-',s)[0]#first West/South
    direction2 = re.findall(r'California-(\w+)',s)[0]#second West/South
    num = int(re.findall(r'California-\w+-(\w+)',s)[0])#10 r 5 or 1 or 3
    return direction1,direction2,num
dd =  sorted(d,key=sorter)

for t in dd:
    print t
```

Output-

```
C:\South-California-North-5.xlsx
C:\West-California-East-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-5.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-10.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
```

example of customization of the `sorter` function-

If you change the sorter function as below i.e discard sorting based on the number-

```
def sorter(s):
    direction1 = re.findall(r'(\w+)-California-',s)[0]#first West/South
    direction2 = re.findall(r'California-(\w+)',s)[0]#second West/South
    num = int(re.findall(r'California-\w+-(\w+)',s)[0])#10 r 5 or 1 or 3
    return direction1,direction2# omitted num here
```

Then output-

```
C:\South-California-North-5.xlsx
C:\West-California-East-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-10.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-5.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
```

### Working proof

**After all you can iterate over them as you want as below-**

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict,OrderedDict

d = ['C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx', 
        'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx',
        'C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx',
        'C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx',
        'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx']

group_data = defaultdict(list)

def sorter(s):
    direction1 = re.findall(r'(\w+)-California-',s)[0]#first West/South
    direction2 = re.findall(r'California-(\w+)',s)[0]#second West/South
    num = int(re.findall(r'California-\w+-(\w+)',s)[0])#10 r 5 or 1 or 3
    return direction1,direction2,num
dd =  sorted(d,key=sorter)

for t in dd:
    key = re.findall(r'([^\d]+)\d',t)[0]
    group_data[key].append(t)

dt = OrderedDict(sorted(group_data.items(),key=lambda x: x[0]))
for it in dt:
    print '\n'.join(dt[it])+'\n'
```

Output-

```
C:\South-California-North-5.xlsx

C:\West-California-East-1.xlsx

C:\West-California-North-5.xlsx
C:\West-California-North-10.xlsx

C:\West-California-South-1.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
C:\West-California-South-3.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of using regex and itertools.groupby:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

filelist =  ['C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx', 
            'C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx', 
            'C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx', 
            'C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx',
            'C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx',
            'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx']

keyfunc = lambda x: re.match('(.*)-\d+\.xlsx', x).group(1)    
keys = [ keyfunc(f) for f in filelist]
grouplist = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(filelist), key = keyfunc)][::-1]
for group in grouplist: print group, '\r\n'
```

The output:

```
['C:\\West-California-South-1.xlsx', 'C:\\West-California-South-3.xlsx'] 

['C:\\West-California-North-10.xlsx', 'C:\\West-California-North-5.xlsx'] 

['C:\\West-California-East-1.xlsx'] 

['C:\\South-California-North-5.xlsx']
```

Comment: I like this method. Can you help me with regex syntax. In this case, what if the changing variable, in this case, the integer, is a string in the middle of the element. Example, C:\\West-California-South-**3PEOPLE**-Blue.xlsx @ccf

Comment: A little complicated. To match it, you can use: `re.match('(.*)-\d[A-Z]+-\w+\.xlsx', x).group(1) `. \d matches one digit number, [A-Z]+ matches upper cases, \w matches letters.